# Undefined error when using send_data in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I have a ruby on rails application which uses send_data in one of the controllers to send a binary data file from the database to the browser. This  functionality works very well when  I do not use jquery/ jquery-mobile. When I use jquery/jquery-mobile then I get an undefined error when I try to invoke the controller/action to download the binary file from the database. Can anyone please suggest a workaround to get this to work ? Thanks.

Additional information:

rhattachments controller code to invoke send_data:

```
def show
  @singlerhattachment = Rhattachment.find(params[:id])  
  send_data @singlerhattachment.hdrattach.file_contents,:type =>    
  @singlerhattachment.hdrattach_content_type, :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

View  code which invokes the above download:

```
<%= link_to hattach.file_name,:action => "show", :controller => "rhattachments",:id => hattach.id %> <br />
```

Comment: With the information you give (or the lack of it), the only workaround I can think of is not to use jQuery.

Comment: I added more details. Tell me what other information do you need ? As I said... it works well w/o jquery but I cannot remove that because I rely on jquery very heavily for other features...

Comment: Firebug tells me that the HTML is malformed and  instead of a valid content type it has Undefined. Any ideas why this would be happening ? The send_data call includes the content type & the table holding the file also has a valid content_type. If I correct the HTML in firebug and refresh the browser the file is displayed...Any ideas as to how this can be corrected ??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and if I added data-ajax="false" to the link  it worked for me.

```
<%= link_to hattach.file_name,:action => "show", :controller => "rhattachments",:id => hattach.id, :data => { "ajax" => false} %> <br />
```